# deploy pypi after sucess travisci

Tags: travis-ci, pypi

I've successfully deployed a package to PyPI using Travis, however I find it deploys no matter scripts are successful or not. How to deploy only if unit tests are successful?

```
language: python
python:
  - '3.6'
os:
  - linux
install:
  - pip install -q -r requirements-dev.txt
  - pip install coverage
  - pip install coveralls
script:
  - python test.py
  - coverage run test.py
after_success:
  - coverage report
deploy:
  provider: pypi
  user: user
  distributions: "bdist_wheel"
  password:
    secure: secure_pẁ
  on:
    tags: false
    branch: dev
```

Comment: could you share a link to the travis logs?

Comment: If the scripts fail, it wont deploy. Could we see the Travis log?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to define two separate [build stages](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/build-stages/), like "Test" and "Deploy", where the "Deploy" stage is [combined](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/build-stages/#build-stages-and-deployments) with a PyPI deployment.